# Rolling back the transaction when API call was already executed

Tags: rest, api, microservices

Recently I've encountered with some problem working with microservices. My main application works with relational databases, the microservice works with Mongo DB and provides ReST API with CRUD methods for some model. CRUD methods are also implemented in the application. A call from the front-end goes to the application first, a new record is created in the relational db (only some of the fields are saved there), then the model is saved externally - in Mongo DB. In the end the transaction is committed. So if something goes wrong and the transaction is rolled back, the API call would already be executed. In the case of creation I can just delete the newly created record from Mongo DB, but in case of Edit I have no idea what to do.

One of the ideas was to overwrite the model in the Mongo DB with the record from the relational database, but in this case the data would be incosistent, as not all the fields are saved there.

Any ideas about this?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of doing this:

**Using a 2PC (2 phase commit)**: you basically request an operation in any distributed service and then confirm/rollback it afterwards.

**Using sagas**: With sagas, you are meant to provide some sort of "rollback operation" for operations you did in your distributed services. When you need to roll back an operation that has already been perform you call the service and indicate a rollback.

More information about sagas here: https://microservices.io/patterns/data/saga.html